# Excel VBA macro to remove each shape's hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with a shape in each row of a column, with more shapes to be added to the column over time.  The problem is, some shapes have hyperlinks and others do not.  I want to write a vba macro to loop through each shape in the column and remove the current shape's hyperlink if it has one.  I have tried recording a macro where I manually remove a shape's hyperlink and then apply this action globally. However, there are other shapes on the sheet that have hyperlinks so my macro must only be applied to this specific column.  Any ideas?

Comment: Post your code. What you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example deletes the hyperlinks from the shapes in Column A, adjust column as necessary.

```
Sub DeleteHyperlink()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim r As Range

        Set r = Columns("A:A")
        For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
            If Not Intersect(Range(shp.TopLeftCell, shp.BottomRightCell), r) Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next
                If shp.Hyperlink.Address <> "" Then shp.Hyperlink.Delete
            End If
        Next shp

    End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the follow procedure to remove all the hyperlinks as once.

```
Sub DeleteHyperLinks()
  Sheet1.Hyperlinks.Delete
End Sub
```